# How to pass selected multiselect picklist and pageblock table values from one vf page to another

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce1-app

I have a multiselect picklist and pageblock table in a visualforce page i want to send the selected multiselect picklist value and modified page block table value to the next visualforce page

This is my vf page code

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Filter based on profiles" collapsible="true" >
     <apex:selectList style="margin-left: 60%;width:150%"  value="{!multival}" size="10" multiselect="true" >
          <apex:selectOptions value="{!Name}"></apex:selectOptions>
     </apex:selectList> 
</apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:commandButton style="margin-left: 30%;width:5%" value="Next" action="{!redirect}"/>
```

This is my first controller code

```
public String multival {get;set;}
public pagereference redirect(){ 
      PageReference redirect = new PageReference('/apex/nextPage?att='+multival);
      redirect.setRedirect(true);
      return redirect;      

}
```

This is my second controller code

```
public class selectedList {
    public String multival {get;set;}
    public selectedList (){
         multival = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('att');
    }
}
```

How do i pass the selected multiselect picklist value to my nextpage?

Comment: Is that controller same for both pages?

Comment: No. controller is different and i have added both the controller code

Comment: @SKH What's the issue you are facing? Where are you stuck with? Did you get any error?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will work. You will get selected values in first vf page in `multival`  variable in controller of `nextpage`. If you debug `multival` in `selectedList` controller, output will look like:

> DEBUG| [1, 4]

You need to extract values from this string as:

```
multival = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('att');
System.debug(multival);   //[1, 4]
String extractedVal = multival.remove('[').remove(']').deleteWhitespace();
System.debug(extractedVal);   //1,4
```

If you need values as a list, use:

```
List<String> extractedVals = extractedVal.split(',');
System.debug(extractedVals);   //(1, 4)
```

Comment: Yes  my approach is working. Is it possible to show the selected values in a dropdown ?

Comment: You can. Add the values you get to a `List<SelectOption>` as you did for first vf page.